# Unsure about the correct application of Miller's Theorem

Tags: transistors, small-signal, parasitic-capacitance

Sorry for the long post but I figured it would be easier to include pictures and all relevant calculations so that there wouldn't be any confusion.

I have a circuit for which I'm trying to analyse and determine the gain. However, I'm unsure about how to use Miller's Theorem to sort out the parasitic capacitance in the small signal model (only just started learning about it).

This is my circuit:

[image: Text]

This is my small signal model:

[image: Text]

Parameters:
$$\beta=100, V_A=100, V_T=26 mV, C_\pi=25pF, C_\mu=1pF$$
$$I_c=1.55mA, g_m=\frac{I_c}{V_T}=0.06, r_\pi=\frac{V_T}{I_B}=1.68k\Omega, r_o=\frac{V_A}{I_c}=64.5k\Omega$$

**My attempt at applying Miller's Theorem:**

$$V_B=-g_mv_\pi(r_o||R_L||C_L)$$
$$V_A=v_\pi$$
$$A_v=\frac{V_A}{V_B}=-g_m(ro||R_L||C_L)=-0.06\times 984.7=-59.1$$
Then,
$$C_\mu^*=A_v\times C_\mu=59.1pF$$
And small signal model becomes:
[image: Small signal model with Miller Theorem adjustments]

Then, circuit gain becomes:

$$A_v=\frac{V_o}{V_{in}}$$
$$V_o=-g_mv_\pi(r_o||R_L||C_L)$$
$$V_\pi=\frac{v_{in}(R_B||r_\pi||(C_\pi+C_\mu^*))}{R_{in}+R_B||r_\pi||(C_\pi+C_\mu^*)}$$
$$V_o=\frac{-g_mv_{in}(R_B||r_\pi||(C_\pi+C_\mu^*))(r_o||R_L||C_L)}{R_{in}+R_B||r_\pi||(C_\pi+C_\mu^*)}$$
$$\implies \frac{V_o}{V_{in}}=\frac{-g_m(R_B||r_\pi||(C_\pi+C_\mu^*))(r_o||R_L||C_L)}{R_{in}+R_B||r_\pi||(C_\pi+C_\mu^*)}=-32.87$$

Does this look like a correct application of Miller's Theorem? Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: fixed equation for \$V_\pi\$, \$V_o\$ and \$\frac{V_o}{V_{in}}\$

Comment: Replace C's with impedance of C, Xc(f)=1 / j2πfC  and XL(f)=j2πfL, but this design is a mess of random RLC parts

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 what do you mean mess of random RLC parts? I was told an inductor positioned on the collector creates an impedance to prevent AC voltage traveling up the collector, and the other capacitors are pretty standard for a transistor amplifier no?

Comment: no !  not at 1kHz with 6 reactive components that cannot be neglected at 1kHz, It's a messy assumption they can be neglected. Restate all your assumptions and  look up RLC impedance nomograph how I use here to make better choices. Where is f in your equations? Why is it missing?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I didn't have a specific operating frequency in mind, the 1kHz on the sine wave was just from simulations - I probably should have clarified. As for f, I've never needed to use frequency to calculate small signal gain - do I need it for the Miller simplification? I'm very confused. I'll check out the RLC impedance monograph though, thanks!

Comment: gain is not determined by L or C alone, rather  by the impedance formula for L and C.  when you don't know the impedance and choose a a random frequency you get an illogical design with a mess of 6 reactive components for no good reason. Don't try to design before you understand the fundamentals